# What kind of building do I get if I upgrade my Pasture building?

Tags: kittens-game

I know if I choose to upgrade my Aquaducts I can then build Hydro Plants, but I don't know what I can build if I upgrade my Pastures... what do I get to build instead of Pastures?

Answer (score 1):

You get to build Solar Farms instead, which produce energy (but no catnip).

According to the [official game wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings&redirect=no), it gives Energy Production 2 (1.5 during winter, 2.66 during summer).

Comment: Actually, pastures don’t **produce** any catnip at all. They reduce the amount that your kittens **consume**. Thus, their effect is proportional to population, not fields, and they’re useless in Iron Will except for the related achievement.